# Найти недостающие элементы в системе координат (массив)

Tags: javascript

Имею например список(массив) из набора точек с координатами.

```
[1,[53.946865249,57.043416178]],[2,[53.947118389,57.043535608]],[3,[53.946607974,57.043553656]],[4,[53.946798082,57.043767565]],[6,[53.946316906,57.044025522]],[8,[53.946048037,57.044154025]],[9,[53.945823274,57.04400278]],[10,[53.94566651,57.044362572]],[11,[53.945625156,57.044096028]],[12,[53.945246109,57.044612473]],[13,[53.945351006,57.044148944]],[14,[53.945053428,57.044775649]],[15,[53.945224546,57.044337295]],[16,[53.944563232,57.045013053]],[17,[53.944955238,57.04450561]],[19,[53.944715477,57.04464065]],[20А,[53.943646,57.045564]],[21,[53.944485343,57.044760069]],[22,[53.943308,57.045731]]
```

требуется найти недостающие элементы между точками в четной и нечетной последовательности, высчитать недостающие от 1 до последней (в приведенном примере это 22) в списке могут иметь место буквенные, например 20А которые нужно как бы пропускать

вывести на экран пропущенные(координаты приведены примерно)

```
[5,[53.946356,57.043710]],[7,[53.946091,57.043846]],[18,[53.944069,57.045272]],[20,[53.946798082,57.043767565]]
```

высчитать между двумя координатами могу и на этом все тупик.

```
x1,y1 = 55.568933911,38.009693681
x2,y2 = 55.568369692,38.009092897
print((x1 + x2)/2, (y1 + y2)/2)
```

найти недостающий как бы тоже

```
const arr = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9];
return arr.find((x,i) => arr[i+1]-x > 1) + 1
//4
```

Comment: А зачем одновременно указывать метки javascript и python если по сути задача вообще арифметическая?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ради эксперимента вот вам решение с помощью pandas. Только имейте в виду, что исходный список должен быть подготовлен (ваше "20A" у меня - явный строковый литерал). В противном случае нужно будет еще обрабатывать исходные данные:

```
import pandas as pd

a = ([1,[53.946865249,57.043416178]],[2,[53.947118389,57.043535608]],[3,[53.946607974,57.043553656]],
     [4,[53.946798082,57.043767565]],[6,[53.946316906,57.044025522]],[8,[53.946048037,57.044154025]],
     [9,[53.945823274,57.04400278]],[10,[53.94566651,57.044362572]],[11,[53.945625156,57.044096028]],
     [12,[53.945246109,57.044612473]],[13,[53.945351006,57.044148944]],[14,[53.945053428,57.044775649]],
     [15,[53.945224546,57.044337295]],[16,[53.944563232,57.045013053]],[17,[53.944955238,57.04450561]],
     [19,[53.944715477,57.04464065]],["20A",[53.943646,57.045564]],[21,[53.944485343,57.044760069]],
     [22,[53.943308,57.045731]])
df = pd.DataFrame([x for x in a if type(x[0])==int]).set_index(0)
df[["x", "y"]] = pd.DataFrame(df[1].tolist(), index=df.index)
df = df.drop(columns=1)
new_idx = range(df.index.min(), df.index.max()+1)
missed_idx = [x for x in new_idx if x not in df.index]
df = df.reindex(new_idx)
res = df.interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)
missed = res.loc[missed_idx]
print(missed)
```

результат:

```
            x          y
0                       
5   53.946557  57.043897
7   53.946182  57.044090
18  53.944835  57.044573
20  53.944600  57.044700
```

UPDATE

я не совсем понял про чёт-нечет, но если нужно интерполировать четные от четных, а нечетные от нечетных, то можно сделать так (после df.reindex(new_index):

```
df.iloc[::2] = df.iloc[::2].interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)
df.iloc[1::2] = df.iloc[1::2].interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)
missed = df.loc[missed_idx]
print(missed)
```

получим:

```
            x          y
0                       
5   53.946346  57.043703
7   53.946085  57.043853
18  53.944145  57.045252
20  53.943726  57.045492
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но решение не совсем верное (между точками в четной и нечетной последовательности) в вашем решении он высчитывает просто между 2-3 данными не учитывая чет/нечет. https://disk.yandex.ru/i/2etKrlVPgijkdw

Comment: я дополнил ответ. вам бы в следующий раз как-то яснее вопрос задавать. желательно с  приведением примера результата.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Извините, начинающий!

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый.

Comment: не совсем. но пусть ;) хотелось бы *.js

Comment: ну так, если не помог, не отмечайте. дело не в баллах, а в статусе вопроса - отвечен или нет.

Comment: а как частично отвечен?

Comment: @TSA21432- тут так не принято! Вы поставили два тега Py. и JS и оставили их даже после того, как вам на это указали. За вас решили (чего тут не делают, но вам, как новичку, пошли на встречу) вашу задачу на одном из указанных языков. И подсказали, как тут поступают, если вам дали правильный ответ. Оказывается, вам надо на другом языке -  так почему тег Pyt. из вопроса не убрали. А если вам надо на двух -  есть решение на Py,  и переписать его на другом - задача для младшего школьника. Вместо этого вы начинаете торговаться "частично отвечен" не частично отвечен. Да тут банить пора за все это.

Comment: Извините. Но с одним тегом не отправляло. И как переписать код с добавлением импорта pandas из Python в js?